# Overflow an integer sequence at a given value

Tags: sequences-and-series, matlab, integers

Sorry, the question seems to be extremely simple, but I fail to find an answer.
I have an integer sequence

```
1, 2, 3, ... 8
```

I would like to convert it to

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

What mathematical operation would give me this result?

An obvious solution is mod: (in Matlab)

```
a = mod(1:8, 4)
```

but it of course results in

```
1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do

> a = mod([1:8]-1,4)+1

or in Python

> (numpy.arange(8) % 4)+1

Comment: Ridiculous!!! :) Thanks!

Comment: Just a tiny correction, it should be: `a = mod([1:8]-1,4)+1`

Comment: @texnic fixed, thank you -- don't have matlab here to test right away...

Comment: I might do `+3` rather than `-1` to keep all numbers positive. This avoids the C++/Java result that `-1%4` evaluates to `-1`. But you might not need to worry about that in Matlab; I think `mod` is actually a modulo function rather than signed remainder.

Comment: @DavidK in C++ this would avoid a `size_t` to `int` conversion as well, which is potentially problematic